# Get data from dropdown menu in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a contact form in laravel 7 and one of the fields is a simple select dropdown, it looks like this:

```
<select name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select ...</option>
   <option value="gen">General</option>
   <option value="sales">Sales</option>
</select>
```

When I send the form, I receive an email with the content the user filled out in the form. When an option is selected, in the email the value is displayed. I'd like to display the actual content of the select option. So not "gen" but "General" should be displayed.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function contactSubmit(Request $request) 
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'msg' => 'min:10'
    ]);

    $data = array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'msg' => $request->msg
    );

    Mail::send('emails.contactemail', $data, function($msg) use($data) {
        $msg->from($data['email']);
        $msg->to('mail@gmail.com');
        $msg->subject('Contact us');
    });
}
```

This is the blade content for the email that is sent out:

```
<strong>From:</strong> {{$name}}
<br>
<strong>Subject:</strong> {{$subject}}
<br>
<strong>Email:</strong> {{ $email }}
<br><br>
<strong>Message:</strong> <br><br>
{{ $msg }}
```

Comment: `<option value="General">General</option>`?

Comment: will there be a problem if you use "General" instead of "gen" in your option value?

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not map these values in your controller?

Answer (score 3):

You can leave out the value attribute, by doing so the value is taken from the text content of the option element.

```html
<select name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select ...</option>
  <option>General</option>
  <option>Sales</option>
</select>
```

Have a look at the docs [Option element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Answer (score 1):

Give value in the option to get the right output

```
<select name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select ...</option>
  <option value="General">General</option>
  <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
</select>
```